# how to not get refreshed when scrolling listview in android

Tags: java, android

i don't want my list view to be refreshed

when i scroll screen list view gets refreshed...

i don't want it to happen...what should i do

```
  <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@id/edittxt_username"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
              />
```

okey editing my real need

am using a checkbox in my listview `

final CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.editcheckbox);

```
                    chb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (chb.isChecked() == true) {
                                CheckedMessages.add(f);

                            } else if (chb.isChecked() == false) {
                                CheckedMessages.remove(f);
                            }
                        }
                    });`
```

suppose there 20 items in list.. i check the first one ..after a scroll i see 6th item checked...again scrollling i see 13th item checked...i tot it might be due to refreshing...whts the reason??

Comment: Why is refreshing bad? What is the _actual_ problem?

Answer (score 2):

When `ListView` is scrolled, it uses `ListAdapter` to show new items. Each time new item becomes visible, `ListView` asks adapter to refresh this item's view . Also `ListView` may cache some items' views for performance reasons.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but you can't disable `ListView` refreshing. That's basically one of the reason `ListView` was implemented in the first place: smart refreshing.

You should describe what you want to achieve, I've got feeling that it's not related with `ListView` refreshing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video about ListView [Google IO 2010 - World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

I think this is not possible. And you have something wrong in your app design.
Please give more details , on why you do not wont your `ListView` items to be refreshed  while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pull To Refresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)