# CustomListview with checkboxes auto checking/unchecking items

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using a custom listview with checkboxes. When i'm scrolling down my listview i see some checkboxes auto checked.When i'm scrolling up some checked from user has been unchecked.

```
class MyListViewAdapterExtras :BaseAdapter<ExtrasPreviewClass>
{
public List<ExtrasPreviewClass> mitems;
private Context mContext;
public MyListViewAdapterExtras(Context context, List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
{
mitems = items;
mContext = context;

}
public override int Count
{
    get
    {
        return mitems.Count;
    }
}
public override long GetItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
public override ExtrasPreviewClass this[int position]
{
    get
    {
        return mitems[position];
    }

}

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExtrasPreview, null, false);

        }

        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
        txtName .Text = mitems[position].Name;
        CheckBox txtCheckBox= row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtCheckBox);
    txtCheckBox.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].CheckBox);

        return row;
    }
```

Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Thats not Java, even close!

Comment: Consider using RecyclerView instead of ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using a custom listview with checkboxes. When i'm scrolling down my listview i see some checkboxes auto checked.When i'm scrolling up some checked from user has been unchecked.

As @Cheticamp said, the views in ListView will be reused during scrolling, and you need to update the view by everytime `getView` get called.

From your codes, you have already the text, but didn't update the `ischecked` state. To achieve that, we need to follow the steps below:

1. Update the Model class(`ExtrasPreviewClass`) to add a bool field to store the `isChecked` state:

   ```
   public class ExtrasPreviewClass
   {
       public ExtrasPreviewClass(string name, string checkbox)
       {
           this.Name = name;
           this.CheckBox = checkbox;
           this.IsChecked = false;
       }
       public String Name { get; set; }

       public String CheckBox { get; set; }

       public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Update your `GetView` method in your adapter and add an event listener class below `GetView`:

   ```
   public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
       View row = convertView;
       if (row == null)
       {
           row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemView, null, false);
       }

       TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);

       txtName.Text = mitems[position].Name;
       CheckBox txtCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtCheckBox);
       txtCheckBox.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].CheckBox);

       //SetOnCheckedChangeListener must be set before txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked
       txtCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(position, ref mitems));
       txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked;
       Console.WriteLine("Set the CheckBox " + position + " to "+ mitems[position].IsChecked);

       return row;
   }

   public class CheckChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
   {
       int position;
       List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items;
       public CheckChangeListener(int position,ref List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
       {
           this.position = position;
           this.items = items;
       }
       public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
       {
           items[position].IsChecked = isChecked;
           Console.WriteLine("Set the " + position + " IsChecked to " + isChecked);
       }
   }
   ```

Notes: `txtCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener` should be called before `txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked`. Otherwise, you will get unexpected behavior.

Update: It is possible to update the view in side of the `ChangeCheckListener`, you need to modify the listener like below:

```
public class CheckChangeListener2 : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    int position;
    List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items;
    View row;
    public CheckChangeListener2(int position, ref List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items,View row)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.items = items;
        this.row = row;
    }
    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
    {
        items[position].IsChecked = isChecked;
        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
        //update the name
        txtName.Text = items[position].Name;
        Console.WriteLine("Set the " + position + " IsChecked to " + isChecked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add  TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);txtName.Text = mitems[position].Name;   On ChangeCheckListener?

Comment: I get this error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'row' of 'MyListViewAdapterExtras.CheckChangeListener.CheckChangeListener(int, ref List<ExtrasPreviewClass>, View)' In this point   //SetOnCheckedChangeListener must be set before txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked
            txtExtrasCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(position, ref mitems));

Comment: Please notice, in my update, the arguments of the constructor has changed, it accepts three arguments now.

Comment: Should i place CheckChangeListener and CheckChangeListener2 toghether or one of them?

Comment: `CheckChangeListener2` is the new version of the `CheckChangeListener`, when you want to add TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);txtName.Text = mitems[position].Name; On ChangeCheckListener.

Comment: I get Error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'row' of 'MyListViewAdapterExtras.CheckChangeListener.CheckChangeListener(int, ref List<ExtrasPreviewClass>, View)' WiOrderAndroid

Comment: After you replaced the `CheckChangeListener`, you will need to modify the line `txtCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(position, ref mitems));` in `GetView` to `txtCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener2(position, ref mitems,row));`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetView()` method, if `convertView` is not `null` then you are reusing a `View`. That view will have the data from whatever position it had been assigned to. If you don't change the data, it will show in a different slot and led to what you are seeing.

To fix this, you will need to make sure that `GetView()` sets all data for the `View` to the correct values for the assigned position regardless of whether the `View` is reused or not.

Here is a link to what I think is a [relevant example](http://techlovejump.com/android-listview-with-checkbox/). I have extracted the `getView()` code and made comments. I hope this helps.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Modified to reuse convertView
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Find the checkBox view
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());

    // Set the checkBox as "checked" or "unchecked" depending upon our internal
    // data structure. Here it is "modelItems[]". If we don't do this, then the checkBox
    // will be set to whatever it was set to if convertView is reused.
    if (modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
        cb.setChecked(true);
    else
        cb.setChecked(false);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,can you give an example of it?

Comment: I get error in getValue.Should i scope getValue inside my class? How will i get value of each checkkbox?

Comment: When the user checks or unchecks a check box, you will need to capture that check/unchecked status and save it in one of your data structures. (This is usually done in an `onClick` listener. ) When you prepare a `View` in `getView()`, you will have to retrieve the appropriate value from that same structure. Here is a better example of a [ListView implementation with checkBoxes](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes.php). I suggest that you work through this example to better understand what you will need to do.

Comment: Something like this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127190/how-to-not-get-refreshed-when-scrolling-listview-in-android

Comment: If you mean the `OnClickListener` then yes. Notice how the status of the check box is captured. That captured value can later be used to repopulate a `ListView` view in `getView()` when it scrolls onto the screen.

Comment: Can i do that from my xml file?(which my listview is placed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I suggest that you go through the demo to get a feel for it.

Comment: The problem is that i'm using xamarin.And my code is in c#, so i dont know how can write many things from java to xamarin

Comment: @Dim Oops! My mistake. I have been pointing you to Java resources.  I can't really help you out wit Xamarin problems. I do believe that you are having the same issue whether c# or Java. Why don't you post a specific question to Stack Overflow and put "Xamarin" in the title. Maybe someone with Xamarin experience will answer.

Comment: Unfortunately if i will post something and put it to xamarin, i will not take any answer.Maybe there arent much people which are use xamerin yet